React App Deployed in Sub-URL on Azure Returns 502 Error for JS and Static Files
I am working with a microservice architecture on Azure where each container is a Quarkus application, and there is one React frontend for now.
Our current setup routes a sub-URL to a container. For example:
https://homepage/dev/frontend/api/v1/web -> Pod in Azure with the React frontend

I deployed my React app as-is to Azure, assuming it would respect the defined homepage property. However, I encounter the following errors when accessing the app:
main.aa438d03.js:1  
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502  

/favicon.ico:1  
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 502  

Note: I don’t have a favicon.ico in my project, so I’m unsure why it is being requested.
When inspecting the Application tab in DevTools, there’s nothing to preview. Additionally, when I try to access the file links, I am redirected to:
homepage/static/js/main.aa438d03.js

Expected Behavior:
The URL should point to:
homepage/dev/frontend/api/v1/web/static/js/main.aa438d03.js

What I Tried So Far:

Set homepage in package.json:
I added the following line to package.json:

"homepage": "/dev/frontend/api/v1/web/"

However, this did not solve the issue.

I verified that the static assets (JS, CSS) are present in the build folder and properly generated.

My Questions:

How can I correctly configure React to work on a sub-URL path like /dev/frontend/api/v1/web?
Why is React attempting to load favicon.ico, even though I don’t have one in the project?
Is there a specific configuration I need on Azure to serve the React static files from the correct path?


Have you deployed the React app to Azure Web App or Azure Static Web App /  AKS?

it is deployed via a container

The 502 error indicates a problem with the server acting as a proxy or gateway.
To deploy the React app with the endpoint dev/frontend/api/v1/web to a container app, use the nginx configuration to build and deploy the image.
Create an nginx.conf file like the following:
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html;

    location /dev/frontend/api/v1/web {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /dev/frontend/api/v1/web/static/ {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/html/static/;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}

After adding the URL in package.json, update your index.js file to include the basename for the router:
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter basename="/dev/frontend/api/v1/web">
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

Alternatively, disable the favicon by modifying public/index.html:
<link rel="icon" href="data:,">

Create a routes.json file in the root directory:
{
    "routes": [
        {
            "route": "/dev/frontend/api/v1/web/*",
            "serve": "/index.html",
            "statusCode": 200
        }
    ]
}

docker-compose.yml:
version: "2"
services:
  nginx-react:
    container_name: ngixreactapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production

Dockerfile:
FROM node:alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn
RUN yarn build
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY --from=build /app/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

Use docker-compose up --build to build and run the container.

Refer to link   for Dockerizing a React App with Nginx.Refer to this link to Run Your React Application On A Sub-path.


Docker Output:

Tag your Docker image with the Azure Container Registry using the following command:
docker tag my-app-nginx-react:latest RegistryName.azurecr.io/my-app-nginx-react:latest 
Push the image using the command:
docker push RegistryName.azurecr.io/my-app-nginx-react:latest 

Create a Container App with the Registry image and change the Ingress settings as shown in the image below:


Browse your Application URL of the Container App, which should look like this:
https://<app-name>.<region>.azurecontainerapps.io/<sub-path>
Output:

